# Button press animation not working with border-radius

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Version
2.0.2

Reproduction link
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=3rSNIU

Platform and OS info
Android

Steps to reproduce
Create button
set css border-radius

What is expected?
worked press animation

What is actually happening?
not showing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected, by applying border radius you modify the default behavior of Android.

You will have to either use plugins like card view / ripple in this case. There is a open [feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1778) to improve support for ripple effects.

Comment: is this problem still not fixed by community. Today i faced the problem.